# How to remove dots only from starting of string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

My string text is Like -

```
1) .....bla ..bla...
2)...bla.. bla…bla.
3).bla.. bla…bla.
```

dots are not static.I want to remove dots only from starting. not All dots

I have tried with this

```
NSString *newString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];
```

but this is removing all dots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this.

```
NSString* regex = @"^\\.*";
NSString* input = @"....abc..z";
NSString* output = [input stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:regex withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range: [input rangeOfString:input]];
```

Comment: NSString* regex = @"^\\\*";

Comment: @Tailor this should go like this: `NSString* regex = @"^\\\\*";`

Comment: @MarekR is correct. my mistake thanks.

Comment: `NSString* regex = @"^\\\\*";` this regex is correct. please share input string.

Answer (score 1):

```
var test = "...abc";

while test.hasPrefix(".") {
    test.remove(at: test.startIndex)
}
//test variable will have dots removed at the start.
```

Try this.

Comment: More elegant and far less stuff to type

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *str = @"...Videt...IDL";

__block NSInteger loc = 0;
[str enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, str.length) options:NSStringEnumerationByWords usingBlock:^(NSString * _Nullable substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    loc = substringRange.location;
    *stop = YES;
}];

NSString *convStr = [str substringFromIndex:loc];
NSLog(@"%@", convStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str = @"....bla .... bla..... bla";
    NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet];
    int letterNO = 0;
    for (int i =0; i<str.length; i++)
    {
        NSString *letter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[str characterAtIndex:i]];
        if ([letter rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            letterNO = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    NSString * newString = [str substringFromIndex:letterNO];
    NSLog(@"newString %@",newString);
```